# PIVOT tabla de una fila y 10 columnas

Tags: sql-server

Estoy intentado transponer una tabla de una fila con 10 columnas y utilizo esto pero me da error en el código:

```
SELECT descripcion
    ,Check01
    ,Check02
    ,Check03
    ,Check04
    ,Check05
    ,Check06
    ,Check07
    ,Check08
    ,Check09
    ,Check10
    ,
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM tabla_resultado_checks
    WHERE descripcion = 'Resultado'
    ) AS tabla_inicial
pivot(Descripcion FOR Descripcion IN (
            Check01
            ,Check02
            ,Check03
            ,Check04
            ,Check05
            ,Check06
            ,Check07
            ,Check08
            ,Check09
            ,Check10
    ) AS pivot_table)
```

El error que estoy recibiendo es el siguiente:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'for'.

No sé si estoy haciendo bien o mal el pivote

Comment: Edita la pregunta y escribe el error que se te está presentando.

Comment: ya lo he actualizado con el error que me sale! Gracias!

Comment: anasavilu, los valores Check01, Check02,...Check10 son columnas de tu tabla? Si esto es correcto, no entiendo muy bien para que quieres hacer una tabla pivote. Puedes explicar con un poco mas de detalle que es lo que deseas hacer.

Comment: lo que quiero es poner los checks en filas y que quede transpuesto, por eso utilizo el pivot, ¿no?

Comment: OK, Entonces lo que necesitas usar es la instrucción UNPIVOT. PIVOT básicamente convierte filas en columnas. UNPIVOT realiza la operación contraria, o sea, gira las columnas de una expresión convirtiéndolas en filas.